# How to assign multiple values in a single variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a array which insert team ID like this,

```
var responsiblePartyId = [];
for (var i in addTeamtask.toteam) {
    responsiblePartyId.push(addTeamtask.toteam[i].SiteUserId);
}
```

I need to get only values from above array and store into single variable.
I tried below, but I assign last value of array.

```
var assignedID;
for (var i = 0; i < responsiblePartyId.length; i++) {
    assignedID= '"' + i, + '"';
}
```

Comment: What is variable used for? What you have now will get overwritten every iteration of the loop

Comment: `'"'+responsiblePartyId.join('","')+'"'`

Comment: I need value from it.

Comment: @santiago, Great job, it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
var assignedID = responsiblePartyId.join(','); // To join all entries with a comma in between
         // If you want them joined using a different character(s), modify accordingly
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Exactly, this is what i thought. thank you so much CBROE!!